Using a datasource in Grafana for API Rest with hmac key authentication
I would like to use a Grafana data source to make API calls (Piano insights) but the service requires an HMAC key authentication. How could I get around this problem? Here is the Piano documentation that shows how to authenticate with postman through a pre-request script:
https://tinypass.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CXPLATPUBLIC/pages/3284795979/Using+POSTMAN+pre-request+script+to+achieve+Cxense+authentication
Thank you!
I try the infinity plugin (https://github.com/grafana/grafana-infinity-datasource) but I was unable to authenticate.
